# Python code stopped working without any changes in code. Installing older version of packages doesn't help. What changed?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, spyder, python-requests-html, undetected-chromedriver

I wrote some code Monday last week that worked. By Wednesday, it did not work. I am scraping data from a website, and by Wednesday the code:

```
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
```

produced error messages that I did not get Monday. My "pre-code" is the following.

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from requests_html import HTMLSession

import requests
import os
import io
import re
```

The selenium package got an update Wednesday.  If I run the code

```
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
```

I get the error message "AttributeError: module 'selenium' has no attribute 'webdriver'" (as well as other output which will be posted below) with the new version of Selenium.

I tried to install the older version of Selenium, the one used last Monday where the code worked fine, only to get the excat same error message. No other packages I use, '`request-html´', '´undetected-chromedriver´' or '´requests´' had any updates between Monday and Wednesday last week.

My computer underwent the following Windows update Wednesday: 2024-02 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8 and 4.8.1 for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64 (KB5034685)

I tried reinstalling Python and manually installing all the packages to the versions I used last Monday and it did not produce anything.

I do not understand what is wrong and I have spent many hours trying to fix it.
If anyone understands what is wrong, I would be most grateful for help. Thank you in advance!<3

Below are the full list of my packages and the full output I get from running the code.

## The full list of packages I use (!pip list):

```
Package                           Version
--------------------------------- ------------
aiobotocore                       2.7.0
aiohttp                           3.9.3
aioitertools                      0.7.1
aiosignal                         1.2.0
alabaster                         0.7.12
altair                            5.0.1
anaconda-anon-usage               0.4.3
anaconda-catalogs                 0.2.0
anaconda-client                   1.12.3
anaconda-cloud-auth               0.1.4
anaconda-navigator                2.5.2
anaconda-project                  0.11.1
anyio                             4.2.0
appdirs                           1.4.4
archspec                          0.2.1
argon2-cffi                       21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings              21.2.0
arrow                             1.2.3
astroid                           2.14.2
astropy                           5.3.4
asttokens                         2.0.5
async-lru                         2.0.4
atomicwrites                      1.4.0
attrs                             23.2.0
Automat                           20.2.0
autopep8                          1.6.0
Babel                             2.11.0
backports.functools-lru-cache     1.6.4
backports.tempfile                1.0
backports.weakref                 1.0.post1
bcrypt                            3.2.0
beautifulsoup4                    4.12.2
binaryornot                       0.4.4
black                             23.11.0
bleach                            4.1.0
blinker                           1.6.2
bokeh                             3.3.4
boltons                           23.0.0
botocore                          1.31.64
Bottleneck                        1.3.7
Brotli                            1.0.9
bs4                               0.0.2
cachetools                        4.2.2
certifi                           2024.2.2
cffi                              1.16.0
chardet                           4.0.0
charset-normalizer                2.0.4
click                             8.1.7
cloudpickle                       2.2.1
clyent                            1.2.2
colorama                          0.4.6
colorcet                          3.0.1
comm                              0.1.2
conda                             24.1.2
conda-build                       24.1.2
conda-content-trust               0.2.0
conda_index                       0.4.0
conda-libmamba-solver             24.1.0
conda-pack                        0.6.0
conda-package-handling            2.2.0
conda_package_streaming           0.9.0
conda-repo-cli                    1.0.75
conda-token                       0.4.0
conda-verify                      3.4.2
constantly                        23.10.4
contourpy                         1.2.0
cookiecutter                      2.5.0
cryptography                      42.0.2
cssselect                         1.2.0
cycler                            0.11.0
cytoolz                           0.12.2
dask                              2023.11.0
datashader                        0.16.0
debugpy                           1.6.7
decorator                         5.1.1
defusedxml                        0.7.1
diff-match-patch                  20200713
dill                              0.3.7
distributed                       2023.11.0
distro                            1.8.0
docstring-to-markdown             0.11
docutils                          0.18.1
entrypoints                       0.4
et-xmlfile                        1.1.0
executing                         0.8.3
fake-useragent                    1.5.1
fastjsonschema                    2.16.2
filelock                          3.13.1
flake8                            6.0.0
Flask                             2.2.5
fonttools                         4.25.0
frozenlist                        1.4.0
fsspec                            2023.10.0
future                            0.18.3
gensim                            4.3.0
gitdb                             4.0.7
GitPython                         3.1.37
gmpy2                             2.1.2
greenlet                          3.0.1
h11                               0.14.0
h5py                              3.9.0
HeapDict                          1.0.1
holoviews                         1.18.3
hvplot                            0.9.2
hyperlink                         21.0.0
idna                              3.4
imagecodecs                       2023.1.23
imageio                           2.33.1
imagesize                         1.4.1
imbalanced-learn                  0.11.0
importlib-metadata                7.0.1
incremental                       22.10.0
inflection                        0.5.1
iniconfig                         1.1.1
intake                            0.6.8
intervaltree                      3.1.0
ipykernel                         6.28.0
ipython                           8.20.0
ipython-genutils                  0.2.0
ipywidgets                        7.6.5
isort                             5.9.3
itemadapter                       0.3.0
itemloaders                       1.1.0
itsdangerous                      2.0.1
jaraco.classes                    3.2.1
jedi                              0.18.1
jellyfish                         1.0.1
Jinja2                            3.1.3
jmespath                          1.0.1
joblib                            1.2.0
json5                             0.9.6
jsonpatch                         1.32
jsonpointer                       2.1
jsonschema                        4.19.2
jsonschema-specifications         2023.7.1
jupyter                           1.0.0
jupyter_client                    8.6.0
jupyter-console                   6.6.3
jupyter_core                      5.5.0
jupyter-events                    0.8.0
jupyter-lsp                       2.2.0
jupyter_server                    2.10.0
jupyter_server_terminals          0.4.4
jupyterlab                        4.0.11
jupyterlab-pygments               0.1.2
jupyterlab_server                 2.25.1
jupyterlab-widgets                3.0.9
keyring                           23.13.1
kiwisolver                        1.4.4
lazy_loader                       0.3
lazy-object-proxy                 1.6.0
lckr_jupyterlab_variableinspector 3.1.0
libarchive-c                      2.9
libmambapy                        1.5.6
linkify-it-py                     2.0.0
llvmlite                          0.42.0
lmdb                              1.4.1
locket                            1.0.0
lxml                              4.9.3
lz4                               4.3.2
Markdown                          3.4.1
markdown-it-py                    2.2.0
MarkupSafe                        2.1.3
matplotlib                        3.8.0
matplotlib-inline                 0.1.6
mccabe                            0.7.0
mdit-py-plugins                   0.3.0
mdurl                             0.1.0
menuinst                          2.0.2
mistune                           2.0.4
mkl-fft                           1.3.8
mkl-random                        1.2.4
mkl-service                       2.4.0
more-itertools                    10.1.0
mpmath                            1.3.0
msgpack                           1.0.3
multidict                         6.0.4
multipledispatch                  0.6.0
munkres                           1.1.4
mypy                              1.8.0
mypy-extensions                   1.0.0
navigator-updater                 0.4.0
nbclient                          0.8.0
nbconvert                         7.10.0
nbformat                          5.9.2
nest-asyncio                      1.6.0
networkx                          3.1
nltk                              3.8.1
notebook                          7.0.8
notebook_shim                     0.2.3
numba                             0.59.0
numexpr                           2.8.7
numpy                             1.26.4
numpydoc                          1.5.0
openpyxl                          3.0.10
outcome                           1.3.0.post0
overrides                         7.4.0
packaging                         23.1
pandas                            2.1.4
pandocfilters                     1.5.0
panel                             1.3.8
param                             2.0.2
paramiko                          2.8.1
parse                             1.20.1
parsel                            1.8.1
parso                             0.8.3
partd                             1.4.1
pathlib                           1.0.1
pathspec                          0.10.3
patsy                             0.5.3
pexpect                           4.8.0
pickleshare                       0.7.5
pillow                            10.2.0
pip                               23.3.1
pkce                              1.0.3
pkginfo                           1.9.6
platformdirs                      3.10.0
plotly                            5.9.0
pluggy                            1.0.0
ply                               3.11
prometheus-client                 0.14.1
prompt-toolkit                    3.0.43
Protego                           0.1.16
protobuf                          3.20.3
psutil                            5.9.0
ptyprocess                        0.7.0
pure-eval                         0.2.2
py-cpuinfo                        9.0.0
pyarrow                           14.0.2
pyasn1                            0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                    0.2.8
pycodestyle                       2.10.0
pycosat                           0.6.6
pycparser                         2.21
pyct                              0.5.0
pycurl                            7.45.2
pydantic                          1.10.12
pydeck                            0.8.0
PyDispatcher                      2.0.5
pydocstyle                        6.3.0
pyee                              11.1.0
pyerfa                            2.0.0
pyflakes                          3.0.1
Pygments                          2.15.1
PyJWT                             2.4.0
pylint                            2.16.2
pylint-venv                       2.3.0
pyls-spyder                       0.4.0
PyNaCl                            1.5.0
pyodbc                            5.0.1
pyOpenSSL                         24.0.0
pyparsing                         3.0.9
pyppeteer                         2.0.0
PyQt5                             5.15.10
PyQt5-sip                         12.13.0
PyQtWebEngine                     5.15.6
pyquery                           2.0.0
PySocks                           1.7.1
pytest                            7.4.0
python-dateutil                   2.8.2
python-dotenv                     0.21.0
python-json-logger                2.0.7
python-lsp-black                  1.2.1
python-lsp-jsonrpc                1.0.0
python-lsp-server                 1.7.2
python-slugify                    5.0.2
python-snappy                     0.6.1
pytoolconfig                      1.2.6
pytz                              2023.3.post1
pyviz_comms                       3.0.0
pywavelets                        1.5.0
pywin32                           305.1
pywin32-ctypes                    0.2.0
pywinpty                          2.0.10
PyYAML                            6.0.1
pyzmq                             25.1.2
QDarkStyle                        3.0.2
qstylizer                         0.2.2
QtAwesome                         1.2.2
qtconsole                         5.4.2
QtPy                              2.4.1
queuelib                          1.6.2
referencing                       0.30.2
regex                             2023.10.3
requests                          2.31.0
requests-file                     1.5.1
requests-html                     0.10.0
requests-toolbelt                 1.0.0
rfc3339-validator                 0.1.4
rfc3986-validator                 0.1.1
rich                              13.3.5
rope                              1.7.0
rpds-py                           0.10.6
Rtree                             1.0.1
ruamel.yaml                       0.17.21
ruamel-yaml-conda                 0.17.21
s3fs                              2023.10.0
scikit-image                      0.22.0
scikit-learn                      1.2.2
scipy                             1.11.4
Scrapy                            2.8.0
seaborn                           0.12.2
selenium                          4.18.1
semver                            2.13.0
Send2Trash                        1.8.2
service-identity                  18.1.0
setuptools                        68.2.2
sip                               6.7.12
six                               1.16.0
smart-open                        5.2.1
smmap                             4.0.0
sniffio                           1.3.0
snowballstemmer                   2.2.0
sortedcontainers                  2.4.0
soupsieve                         2.5
Sphinx                            5.0.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp           1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp             1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp            2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath              1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp              1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml     1.1.5
spyder                            5.4.3
spyder-kernels                    2.4.4
SQLAlchemy                        2.0.25
stack-data                        0.2.0
statsmodels                       0.14.0
streamlit                         1.30.0
sympy                             1.12
tables                            3.9.2
tabulate                          0.9.0
tblib                             1.7.0
tenacity                          8.2.2
terminado                         0.17.1
text-unidecode                    1.3
textdistance                      4.2.1
threadpoolctl                     2.2.0
three-merge                       0.1.1
tifffile                          2023.4.12
tinycss2                          1.2.1
tldextract                        3.2.0
toml                              0.10.2
tomlkit                           0.11.1
toolz                             0.12.0
tornado                           6.3.3
tqdm                              4.65.0
traitlets                         5.7.1
trio                              0.25.0
trio-websocket                    0.11.1
truststore                        0.8.0
Twisted                           23.10.0
twisted-iocpsupport               1.0.2
typing_extensions                 4.9.0
tzdata                            2023.3
tzlocal                           2.1
uc-micro-py                       1.0.1
ujson                             5.4.0
undetected-chromedriver           3.5.5
Unidecode                         1.2.0
urllib3                           1.26.18
validators                        0.18.2
w3lib                             2.1.2
watchdog                          2.1.6
wcwidth                           0.2.5
webdriver-manager                 4.0.1
webencodings                      0.5.1
websocket-client                  0.58.0
websockets                        10.4
Werkzeug                          2.2.3
whatthepatch                      1.0.2
wheel                             0.41.2
widgetsnbextension                3.5.2
win-inet-pton                     1.1.0
wrapt                             1.14.1
wsproto                           1.2.0
xarray                            2023.6.0
xlwings                           0.29.1
xyzservices                       2022.9.0
yapf                              0.31.0
yarl                              1.9.3
zict                              3.0.0
zipp                              3.17.0
zope.interface                    5.4.0
zstandard                         0.19.0
```

## **Full error message:**

```
[autoreload of selenium.webdriver.common.proxy failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 276, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 500, in superreload
    update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 397, in update_generic
    update(a, b)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 330, in update_class
    old_obj = getattr(old, key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\proxy.py", line 61, in __get__
    return getattr(obj, self.name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'autodetect'
]
[autoreload of selenium.webdriver.common.options failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 276, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 500, in superreload
    update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 397, in update_generic
    update(a, b)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 330, in update_class
    old_obj = getattr(old, key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\options.py", line 49, in __get__
    return obj._caps.get(self.name)
           ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_caps'
]
[autoreload of selenium.webdriver.common.print_page_options failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 276, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 500, in superreload
    update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 397, in update_generic
    update(a, b)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 330, in update_class
    old_obj = getattr(old, key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\print_page_options.py", line 63, in __get__
    return obj._page.get(self.name, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_page'
]
[autoreload of selenium.webdriver.common.timeouts failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 276, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 500, in superreload
    update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 397, in update_generic
    update(a, b)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 330, in update_class
    old_obj = getattr(old, key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\timeouts.py", line 46, in __get__
    return getattr(obj, self.name) / 1000
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_implicit_wait'
]
[autoreload of selenium.webdriver.ie.options failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 276, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 500, in superreload
    update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 397, in update_generic
    update(a, b)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 330, in update_class
    old_obj = getattr(old, key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\options.py", line 70, in __get__
    return obj._options.get(self.name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_options'
]
[autoreload of selenium.webdriver.safari.options failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 276, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 500, in superreload
    update_generic(old_obj, new_obj)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 397, in update_generic
    update(a, b)
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 330, in update_class
    old_obj = getattr(old, key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\B363201\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\safari\options.py", line 52, in __get__
    return obj._caps.get(self.name)
           ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_caps'
]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[40], line 28
    driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py:279 in __init__
    else selenium.webdriver.common.service.utils.free_port()

AttributeError: module 'selenium' has no attribute 'webdriver'
```

I tried to install the older version of Selenium, the one used last Monday where the code worked fine, only to get the excat same error message. No other packages I use, 'request-html', 'undetected-chromedriver' or 'requests' had any updates between Monday and Wednesday last week.

I tried reinstalling Python and manually installing all the packages to the versions I used last Monday and it did not produce anything.

Comment: "I tried to install the older version of Selenium, ..., only to get the excat same error message." Chances are you installed it somewhere on your system; however, that is not the place Jupyter is using. Run `%pip list` in your notebook. Not with the exclamation point. You should be using an exclamation point with `pip` as it runs off in a temporary shell that isn't necessarily in the environment where you are running the kernel backing Jupyter. Always us the magic varations of the commands added in 2019.

Comment: I'd be cautious though. I'm not sure you are chasing the correct issue. Also, in the future you should use environment managing software like Anaconda to insulate you from such issues. If you are indeed describing things correctly. In fact, I see Anaconda listed and so you should be using Jupyter through that and managing all installs through that. Only resorting to `pip` for anything that Anaconda/conda doesn't handle. I know there's a recipe for selenium and so `pip` should not be in your equation here. Use `%conda list` in your notebook that you open via the Anaconda navigator.

Comment: i would follow the official docs here:  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/